# Update/delete data from Datagrid

Tags: c#, database, winforms, datagrid

I'm new in the C#/Database world. I just created a C# project, connected it to a database and filled a datagrid from a table.

I didn't write any code so far, just using the Visual C# wizard and few drag-and-drops. My grid is now showing data retrieved from a table, but I can't update or delete rows.
So, how do I update or delete rows from the database and validate it?
This is my page form1.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Learn
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void userBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Validate();
            this.userBindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.usersDataSet);
        }       

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'usersDataSet.User' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.userTableAdapter.Fill(this.usersDataSet.User);
        }

        private void userDataGridView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void bindingNavigatorDeleteItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Code to delete an item
        }

        private void bindingNavigatorAddNewItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Code to add an item
        }
    }
}
```

So, I need now to perform update and delete, any help will greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which UI framework? WinForms, WPF, Silverlight, ASP.NET WebForms, LightSwitch?

Comment: Desktop, a windows form.

Comment: Added the "winforms" tag for you.

Comment: Ah, thank you, still waiting for any help.

Answer (score 0):

To validate data when you are updating it, you would subscribe to the RowValidating event and process validation there.  Please refer to this example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowvalidating.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To delete from a table is just a matter of,

```
connStr = ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\temp\\Set.mdb;Persist Security Info=False");
        try
        {
            //Empty the table
            sql = "Delete from " + table;
            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn))
                {
                    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
```

I dont know about the rest as in validating the data I have a similar related question open.